# Pros/ Cons of using one big include file

Tags: c++, include, header-files

I've got a personal project, which I doubt would exceed 20 pairs of header/cpp files. I was wondering whether it would be better to have each header and cpp file include the other files that it needs (or use forward declarations), or have every file include "Includes.hpp" which in turn includes all of the standard libraries, gives a forward declaration for each class, then includes all of my other headers.

As I can see, using one big header file:

- Cleans everything up
- Makes it easier to include these files from other directories (as you only need to navigate to use one file, which then links all of the others)
- Will include all files for every compilation, which considering this is a small project, isn't a disadvantage, as I'll be using all of the files

Is this a good idea?

Comment: For one, It gives you increased build times.      
Every time you modify even a trivial thing, all the source files will need compilation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that *in general* this is a bad idea for several reasons:

- It gives you poor encapsulation: clients should just pull in the headers they need. With this approach the inclusion will pull in everything, which as Alok mentions will increase build time and sensitivity to rebuilds
- There's no distinction between interface classes and implementation classes, ie those that clients of your library use and ones that are used internally by this library that clients don't need to (and perhaps shouldn't) see
- If any of your headers define macros then these may now 'leak' into any other code that includes the header, which may be undesirable. Anyone who's ever had to type `#undef MIN` will know this pain.
- There's a possibility of recursive inclusion if you have several classes that need to be aware of each other, so it may be sensitive to the order of inclusion or you'll get include cycles

I think though there is one instance where it may be acceptable, which is if your library only provides a few classes/functions that are intended to be called by clients, and all the rest are just internal classes used by the implementation. So clients can just include `mylib.h` and that's all they need to worry about. This also makes it easier if you want to compile your library as a static library as you can just distribute the library and one header.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest I wouldn't do it. You mentioned your project will have just about 20 cpp files, but you did not mention how big these files will be and how complex code they will contain. If you put everything into one big header, every time you will have to recompile those 20 files, and if those files contain a lot of code, that will make compile-time increase significantly.

Of course if all you want to include in the big header are headers from the standard library or headers you won't modify, then you can put them all in a pre-compiled header and let all of your cpp files include it.

However, if there are headers you are going to modify (e.g. change class definitions, add typedefs, whatever), you should be aware that each modification will require a recompilation all of the cpp files. Depending on the size of those files, each small edit (change a function name, add a whitespace, add a comment) might delay your work by one minute when it could take five seconds (and if you're using more complex library such as Boost.Spirit, those times go up really quick).

To conclude, if you are working on a project that you will need to maintain I would not put everything into a single file, even if the project is small *now*.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

The use of *convenience* headers do exist, mind, they can be used to package functionalities that come together, and it is also possible to prefer an `include` to a forward declaration in a header file if you think that 90% of the time the clients of the header will also require the full definition of the included object anyway.

However a Global Header is bad style, and whilst your project is small now, it may grow later on. Having had to unravel this kind of things and resplit the headers, I can only say: no fun...

And what is the gain anyway ? If the project is small, there are few headers to begin with, so it's marginal.